# drag and drop image ordering which saves to database upon completion/event - Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, drag-and-drop

We have a database table of property images:

```
imgID (int), propertyID (int), imgfilename (nvarchar), imgdisplayorder (int)
```

These are displayed in order of imgdisplayorder, ascending.

We'd like a facility that allows our user to drag and drop images into the order they'd prefer and then for it to save that information to database, updating the imgdisplayorder field with the new order.  Is that possible?  I've only been able to find jQuery tools that do the drag and dorp but not tools that save the resulting order to database.

We're using Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

It's all possible and quite simple if you use jQuery and something like sortable or drag+drop from jQueryUI.

You are going to have to do the reordering client side then pass the information to the server side to process in Classic ASP.

You can either update the order every time the order changes using AJAX and creating an ASP page to process the AJAX. Here's an example of this using jQueryUI sortable and Classic ASP: http://halnesbitt.com/blog/2010/08/05/save-order-with-jquery-ui-sortable-and-aspaccess/

Or you could use similar code to above to put the order (which is in a comma separated string in the above example) into a hidden field and then process this when the form is submitted. This is usually the best approach so all your changes are saved when you click submit, rather than everytime you drag and drop.

In that example, see the following JavaScript code:

```
update : function () { 
    var order = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize'); 
    //alert(order);
    $("#info").load("update-order.asp?"+order); 
}
```

This is the event for when the order is changed, and this calls an ASP script to make the change. This could be changed to update a hidden field instead, eg.

```
update : function () { 
    var order = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize'); 
    //alert(order);
    $("#HiddenFieldID").val(order); 
}
```

Then similar ASP code to the example could be used to process the form.

Hopefully that's pointed you in the right direction.